# Get value with max count from each key with multiple values Python dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a dictionary which looks like the following:

```py
{
    'max_depth': [15, 20, 35, 20, 20],
    'min_samples_split': [1, 5, 5, 3, 2],
    'n_estimators': [50, 50, 50, 10, 10]
}
```

I would like to return the following, where values are those which occur most frequently:

```py
{
    'max_depth': 20,
    'min_samples_split': 5,
    'n_estimators': 50
}
```

I have tried the following:

```py
def most_freq_param(param_data_col):
    out = []

    #model params
    param_list = list(ast.literal_eval(param_data_col.iloc[1]).keys())

    params = {}
    max_params = {}     

    for i in range(len(param_list)): #create empty dict of params
        params[param_list[i]] = []
        max_params[param_list[i]] = []

    for i in range(len(param_data_col)):
        out.append(ast.literal_eval(param_data_col.iloc[i]))

    for value in out:
        for param in params:
            for i in range(len(param_list)):
                params[param].append(value[param_list[i]])

    for param in max_params:
        lst = params.get(param)
        max_value = max(lst,key=lst.count)
        max_params[param].append(max_value)

    return max_params
```

Comment: Can you solve the problem for an individual list? Have you made any attempt at the problem?

Comment: Python collections are worth learning: https://stackabuse.com/introduction-to-pythons-collections-module/

Answer (score 0):

For the given dictionary, 
params = {'max_depth': [15,20,35,20,20], 'min_samples_split': [1,5,5,3,2], 'n_estimators': [50,50,50,10,10]}

With the below code you can get the required output: {'max_depth': 20, 'min_samples_split': 5, 'n_estimators': 50}

```
from statistics import mode
d = {'max_depth': [15,20,35,20,20], 'min_samples_split': [1,5,5,3,2], 'n_estimators': [50,50,50,10,10]}
max_params = {}
for key, value in d.items():
    max_params[key] = mode(d[key])
```

You can also use collection module:

```
from collections import Counter
d = {'max_depth': [15,20,35,20,20], 'min_samples_split': [1,5,5,3,2], 'n_estimators': [50,50,50,10,10]}
max_params = {}
for key, value in d.items():
    max_params[key] = Counter(d[key]).most_common(1)[0][0]
```

Read about collections in detail: https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html

Now you can use any of the above block of code in your function to get the most frequent parameters